# AWS-issued certificate failure

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a certificate issued by AWS for my domain, and as informed I configured it on register.com. Problem is that when I open the site with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it appears as an invalid certificate, but when I open it directly with https://example.com it appears a valid certificate.

I am using NodeJS as a server, how do I redirect to always open the domain like https://example.com ?

Now is working like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Locale, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding, Content-Encoding');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Locale');

    if ((req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] || "").endsWith("http")) {
        res.redirect(`https://${req.headers.host}${req.url}`); 
    }    
    next();
});
```

My certificate

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to do a redirect, or how to get your certificate to work with www?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your SSL certificate for **both** `www.example.com` and `example.com`. Registering only one, will not work because `www.example.com` will be considered as different than `example.com`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. First time I do this configuration. Can I redirect any request to https://example.com? I saw, I think I have ti generate another certificate to fix this issue.

Comment: I saw this post about my doubt about add domain to the existing post -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194494/how-to-add-a-domain-to-an-existing-ssl-certificate-on-aws

Comment: @RobertoVieira You can redirect. But for  SSL cert, you have to delete the existing one, and create new one with both domains.